# argument by name color scheme pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

I am on PyCharm 2017.1.4 with Darcula theme.
I don't see how to change the color of the named argument, which is currently undistinguishable for me.
I have been into Editors > Colors & Fonts but it seems that everything is tunable apart from that.

[image: example of bad argument name coloring]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What type of file is this? In PyCharm you can configure different color settings for different types of files. Since this is tagged with PyCharm and Python, I'm going to assume it's a Python file. If it's a different kind of file, select the correct type of file instead of `Python`.

`Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Python | Keyword argument`

Side note, I looked at Darcula, and what you show does not look like `Darcula` for `Python`. If you really are using Python, I would consider `Restore Defaults...` for your color scheme, or looking into it more because something seems off to me. This is what `Darcula` looks like to me.

[image]

Comment: it was python and darcula indeed. Maybe I changed some colors without nothing it. anyway, thanks !